# Как держать определенную часть background`а по центру?

Tags: javascript, css, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте. Возникла следующая задача. У главного экрана есть фон. И когда экран сужается, изображение должно стремиться определенной точкой к центру. В данном случае - фэйс. Привожу вид на дэсктопе и смартфоне. 
Временно скостылил медиазапросами, но нужна именно плавная подстройка бэкграунда, и чтоб он не выехал, оставив пустую вертикальную полосу (как это сейчас у меня иногда бывает).. Без JS тут не обойтись, как понимаю. Подмогните, пожалуйста, кому не трудно!:)

[image: Нормальный вид на дэсктопе]
[image: Фэйс должен выравниваться по центру]

Comment: Можно попробовать положить фон в отдельный блок и поэкспериментировать с transform'ом.

Comment: а как начсет background-position?

Comment: `background-position: center`

Comment: @Duoxx, не уверен, что можно применить. Хотя может и полкчится.

Comment: @HamSter, так у него не в центре же?

Comment: @HamSter, так у него не в центре же?

Comment: можно с transform`ом, можно с background-position, я медиа-запросами двигал бэкграунд влево в зависимости от ширины экрана, но медиа-запросы - это СТУПЕНЧАТОЕ решение проблемы, а мне нужно ПЛАВНО пододвигать нос рисунка к центру экрана в зависимости от ширины экрана. Нос бэкграунда - это не центр, как можно видеть из 1го скриншота, поэтому background-position: center не прокатит

Comment: @Александр вы в вопросе про нос не написали

Comment: Конкретно слова НОС не фигурировало, но было слово фэйс. А центр фэйса - это нос:)

Answer (score 3):

После мозгового штурма и извращений, вышло примерно вот это (сжимаем браузер)

```
function getOffset (width) {
                //y=kx+b
                var k = -1.1;
                if (width< 680){
                    /*если ширина экрана менее 680пк,
                    то делаем квадратичную зависимость
                    коэффициента k от ширины экрана*/
                    var a = -13/2880000;
                    var b = 221/36000;
                    var c = -5737/1800; 
                    k = width*width*a + width*b + c;
                }
                var b = 1600;
                var offset = (k * width) + b;
                offset = Math.floor(offset);

                if ( offset < 0 ){
                        offset = 0;
                }

                return -offset;
            };
```

https://codepen.io/AvonavI/pen/jwpPGw

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `background-position:right center;`:

```css
div{
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPsbm.jpg)no-repeat right center /cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:90%"></div>
<div style="width:80%"></div>
<div style="width:70%"></div>
<div style="width:60%"></div>
<div style="width:50%"></div>
<div style="width:40%"></div>
<div style="width:30%"></div>
<div style="width:20%"></div>
<div style="width:10%"></div>
```